# Sharepoint 2013 Rest API - oData $filter query is still remembering white space I eliminated in javascript

Tags: javascript, rest, sharepoint, odata, sharepoint-2013

I'm trying to create a custom input field with autocomplete features in my Sharepoint page.  I'm using the Rest API to $filter the input value using "substringof."  So far it's working but now I'm trying to consider if people typed in spaces.
For example, if someone typed " Joe" instead of "Joe" then it will no longer find results. Hence, I tried to eliminate the blank spaces with Javascript but the query is still not providing results when there are blank spaces.  Anyone have a clue why? Here is my function below:

```
function q_Names(term){
var termSplit = term.split(";");
var t = termSplit[termSplit.length-1].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + termSplit[termSplit.length-1].slice(1);
//var q = t.split(" ").join("");
var q = t.replace(/\s+/g, '');
if(q.length>1){
    alert(path + "web/siteusers?$select=Id,Title&$filter=substringof('"+q+"',Title)");
    $.ajax({
        url: path + "web/siteusers?$select=Id,Title&$filter=substringof('"+q+"',Title)",
        type: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept":  "application/json;odata=verbose" },
        success: function(data){ 
            //alert( JSON.stringify(data) );
            var str = ""
            for(var i=0; i<data.d.results.length; i++){
                str=str + "<div><a href='javascript:acf_author();'>";
                str=str + data.d.results[i].Title + "</a></div>";
            }
            $("#ac_Author").html(str);
        },
        error: function(data){ alert('could not find user!'); }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: Is it providing results for the the ones without spaces?

Comment: Yes, if there are no white spaces, it works like a charm

Comment: Its not working if text contains spaces.. any solution?